# Post request fail with error 400 Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, http, xunit

When I create a post request using `HttpClient` I got error 400:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type....

```json
{
    "draft": {
        "data": "draft in EN",
        "type": "draft text ",
        "date": "2021-04-12T11:44:05.065Z"
    }
}
```

The same request with Postman is fine.

Here is the code:

```cs
var typeNew = new Draft() {
  Comment = "Some comment.",
  data = "draft in EN",
  type = "draft text",
  date = DateTime.Now, 
};
var typeNewJson = new JObject();
typeNewJson["draft"] = JObject.FromObject(typeNew); 
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{servicePath}/api/ldraft/new", typeNewJson);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have?

Comment: var typeNew = new Draft()
                {
                    Comment = "Some comment.",
                    data = "draft in EN",
                    type = "draft text",

                    date = DateTime.Now,
           
                };

                var typeNewJson = new JObject();
                typeNewJson["draft"] = JObject.FromObject(typeNew);

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{servicePath}/api/ldraft/new", typeNewJson);

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: please edit the question and add the code there and not in comments so we can read it and try to help!

Comment: but as the error message says, you are deserializing the response in a variables that are not compatible with the last.

Comment: @Warios yes that is the error: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Draft' because the type requires a JSON object . it is no joke

Comment: My friend, I asked for the code, the error is clear.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not sure you serialize your object properly and then you need to also deserialize back to get your JSON response.
Try the code snippet below:

```
var pObject = new ObjectToPost {
// pass in your signature here
}
 var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 var response = await client.PostAsync(Uri, stringContent);
 if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     //handle error here
 }
 string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var stringResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Draft>(jsonResponse);

//You can go ahead to return whatever data/property you wish to return from your string response


 public class Draft
 {
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
 }
```

**Note: pObject is the C# object you're trying to post while the class Draft is to represent the structure of your JSON response for deserialization.**

Comment: Thanks @yemo1 the problem it was missing of that line:                                                       var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");     i could not find the logical reason but that was the problem

Comment: Hi Alexa, 
Good to know, the logical reason is that HTTP needs to accept and process data in a format it understands, in this case JSON, hence reason for serializing the C# object into JSON.